How to tell WolfranAlpha that variables given in the equation are positive integers?
This question is similar to one here, but it's not the same.
So, I want to ask WolframAlpha with math input (I don't know natural language) if the following identity holds (of course it does, it's a recurrence for binomials):
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}$$ for $n, k$ positive integers.
How can I do that?
My tries: first: Is \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!k!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}? - gives it is not true - it gives counterexamples with negative fractions.
second: Is \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} = frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!k!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!} assuming n, k natural? - doesn't give an answer if it is true or not.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ ?

Submit as  n!/(k!(n-k)!)-((n-1)!/((n-k-1)!k!)+(n-1)!/((n-k)!(k-1)!))

@Randall Thank you, I will post similar questions there in future.

This question is off-topic here.  I will poke the Mathematica mods, and see if they want it on [mathematica.se].  If yes, I will migrate it.

There are a couple of ways to do this:
(1) use Assuming and Element. For example:
Assuming[Element[n|k,Integers] && n > 0 && k > 0, some expression]
(2) use Refine. For example
Refine[something to refine, n > 0 && k > 0 && Element[n|k,Integers]]
(3) use Reduce. For example
Reduce[expression to reduce && n > 0 && k > 0, {n,k}, Integers]
Here are some examples on using assumptions from the official documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AlgebraicManipulation.html#31833

Thank you. If I type Refine[Factorial[n]/(Factorial[k] * Factorial[n - k]) == Factorial[n - 1]/(Factorial[n - k - 1] * Factorial[k] ) + Factorial[n - 1]/(Factorial[n - k] * Factorial[k - 1]) or any other function you provided I get the following error message: Oops, you've exceeded the maximum number of characters.

Another example which produces the same error problem: Assuming[Element[n|k,Integers] && n > 0 && k > 0, Factorial[n]/(Factorial[k] * Factorial[n - k]) == Factorial[n - 1]/(Factorial[n - k - 1] * Factorial[k] ) + Factorial[n - 1]/(Factorial[n - k] * Factorial[k - 1])]

Where are you doing this, WolframAlpha? What is in my answer is for Mathematica, since that's what was in your question. Note also that WolframAlpha and Mathematica aren't always interchangeable.

Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing that out.
